# Emacs incorrectly looking for .el instead of .elc

Tags: emacs, elisp

I recently started using django-html-mumamo-mode which is part of nXhtml in emacs and everything seems to work except that when I start writing javascript code in an html page, I get the warning/error

```
Can't find library /usr/share/emacs/23.2/lisp/progmodes/js.el
```

I checked in that folder and all of the files have the `.elc` extension including `js.elc`, which is probably why emacs can't find it. Can I change something to make emacs just load the `.elc` file?

**Edit:** This continues to occur if I run `M-x load-library js` or `M-x load-library js.elc`

**Edit2:** I have confirmed that `load-suffixes` is set to `("el" "elc")`, and that js.elc is in the `progmodes` folder, which is in `load-path` and that all users have read permissions for that file. I am using emacs version 23.2.1, and when I set `debug-on-error` to `t` I got a traceback, and it looks like the following part contains the error:

```
error("Can't find library %s" "/usr/share/emacs/23.2/lisp/progmodes/js.el")                                                                                                                         
find-library-name("/usr/share/emacs/23.2/lisp/progmodes/js.el")                                                                                                                                     
find-function-search-for-symbol(js-indent-line nil "/usr/share/emacs/23.2/lisp/progmodes/js.elc")                                                                                                   
(let* ((lib ...) (where ...) (buf ...) (pos ...)) (with-current-buffer buf (let ... ... ... ...)) (put fun (quote mumamo-evaled) t))                                                                
(if (get fun (quote mumamo-evaled)) nil (let* (... ... ... ...) (with-current-buffer buf ...) (put fun ... t)))                                                                                     
(unless (get fun (quote mumamo-evaled)) (let* (... ... ... ...) (with-current-buffer buf ...) (put fun ... t)))                                                                                     
(progn (unless (get fun ...) (let* ... ... ...)))                                                                                                                                                   
(if mumamo-stop-widen (progn (unless ... ...)))                                                                                                                                                     
(when mumamo-stop-widen (unless (get fun ...) (let* ... ... ...)))
```

Notably, the third line contains a reference to the correct file, but it ends up trying to load the wrong one. Has anyone seen this kind of thing before or have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please enable `(setq debug-on-error t)` in order to see what code throws this error. Perhaps the mode incorrectly wants to load the `.el` file specifically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read the section in the Emacs manual on ["How Programs Do Loading](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/How-Programs-Do-Loading.html), the js.elc file **should** be loaded if normal library -loading commands (e.g. - "require", "autoload", "load-file", etc) are being used. Some things to do to debug this:

1. Does your userid have system security permissions to access the js.el file in that location?
2. If you type <kbd>M-x emacs-version</kbd>, what version of Emacs are you running?
3. The "load-library" command searches for lisp files in the "load-path". When you examine the contents of your load-path, is the specified directory in it?
4. Set the variable "debug-on-error" to "t" and re-attempt to write javascript code in an html page - when the error occurs, check the source line where the error occurs and, if it's not apparent from that what is causing the problem, post an update to your question with a few lines of the source where the error occurred as well as the stack trace that was produced by Emacs.

**EDIT:** Ok, now that you've added the stack trace, it's possible to see why the error is occurring. Here are the key lines from the "find-function-search-for-symbol" function (which is the function where the error is occurring in):

```
(when (string-match "\\.el\\(c\\)\\'" library)
  (setq library (substring library 0 (match-beginning 1))))
;; Strip extension from .emacs.el to make sure symbol is searched in
;; .emacs too.
(when (string-match "\\.emacs\\(.el\\)" library)
  (setq library (substring library 0 (match-beginning 1))))
(let* ((filename (find-library-name library))
```

In line#2, the function is setting the library name equal to the "*.elc" library name minus the "c" (e.g. it's converting it from "/usr/share/emacs/23.2/lisp/progmodes/js.elc" to "/usr/share/emacs/23.2/lisp/progmodes/js.el". Then, in line#7 of the above code, it's trying to find that source member (and failing as it doesn't exist). Looking further at the stack trace, the key line is:

```
(if (get fun (quote mumamo-evaled)) nil (let* (... ... ... ...) (with-current-buffer buf ...) (put fun ... t)))
```

which is called in the nXhtml "mumamo-funcall-evaled" function. The author of nXhtml obviously has not considered that the ".elc" file may exist but that the ".el" is not in the same directory. It appears that he used to distribute js.el with nXhtml but stopped doing so since it is now shipped with most recent Emacs distributions. So, in his environment, he probably has the ".el" files in the same directory as the ".elc" files and hasn't encountered this problem.So, you should probably do 2 things:

1. Notify the author of the nXhtml library so that he can fix the bug in his code.
2. Copy the necessary ".el" source files to "/usr/share/emacs/23.2/lisp/progmodes/" so that you don't get the error. Alternatively, you may choose to re-install js.el (and possibly some other modules) in another directory and put that directory ahead of "/usr/share/emacs/23.2/lisp/progmodes/" in your "load-path".

Doing #1 will get the problem fixed in the long-term while doing #2 should let you use nXhtml in the short-term.

Comment: I added the values you requested in my answer.

Comment: Ok, the stack trace was helpful as it identified the cause of the problem. I've updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I submitted a bug report, but where can I find the .el source files for the temporary solution?

Comment: js.el is part of Emacs since version 23.2 so you can get it from the official Emacs distribution or download it from the Bazaar or Git repositories (see: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsDevelopmentSources)

Comment: On ubuntu I installed the package "emacs23-el" and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Check your value of `load-suffixes`

`C-h v load-suffixes`. You probably want this to be something like `(".elc" ".el")`. If it is make sure that your mode hasn't set it to something weird, or bound it dynamically.

Comment: I added in my answer that `load-suffixes` is set to `(".elc" ".el")`, but I do not know how to check if the mode changes it.